# I can't collect the logs in the given expression

Tags: functions, syntax

Please, see better [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152839/i-cant-collect-the-logs-in-the-given-expression-continuation) question, since it displays the problem better, i.e., more specifically.

I have complicated function:

```
F[s2_, Ss_, t1_, m_, m2_] := 
 Evaluate[-6 ((s2^6 + (Ss - 7 t1) s2^5 + (-4 Ss^2 + 13 t1 Ss + 
            16 t1^2) s2^4 + 
         2 (Ss^3 - 13 t1 Ss^2 - 10 t1^2 Ss - 8 t1^3) s2^3 + 
         t1 (18 Ss^3 + 6 t1 Ss^2 - 4 t1^2 Ss + 7 t1^3) s2^2 + 
         t1^2 (18 Ss^3 + 22 t1 Ss^2 + 11 t1^2 Ss - t1^3) s2 + 
         Ss t1^3 (2 Ss^2 + 2 t1 Ss - t1^2)) m^6 - 
      Ss (s2 - t1) ((11 t1 - 2 Ss) s2^4 + 
         2 (Ss^2 - 16 t1 Ss - 7 t1^2) s2^3 + 
         6 (4 Ss^2 t1 - t1^3) s2^2 + 
         2 t1^2 (15 Ss^2 + 16 t1 Ss + 5 t1^2) s2 + 
         t1^3 (4 Ss^2 + 2 t1 Ss - t1^2)) m^4 + 
      Ss^2 (s2 - t1)^2 (s2^4 - (Ss + 9 t1) s2^3 + 
         3 (3 Ss - t1) t1 s2^2 + t1^2 (15 Ss + 11 t1) s2 + 
         Ss t1^3) m^2 + 
      Ss^3 (s2 - t1)^3 t1 (s2^2 - 4 t1 s2 + t1^2)) Log[((-m^2 + m2^2 +
         s2 - Sqrt[m^4 - 2 (m2^2 + s2) m^2 + (m2^2 - s2)^2]) (s2 - 
        t1))/(2 s2)] s2^3 + 
   6 ((s2^6 + (Ss - 7 t1) s2^5 + (-4 Ss^2 + 13 t1 Ss + 
            16 t1^2) s2^4 + 
         2 (Ss^3 - 13 t1 Ss^2 - 10 t1^2 Ss - 8 t1^3) s2^3 + 
         t1 (18 Ss^3 + 6 t1 Ss^2 - 4 t1^2 Ss + 7 t1^3) s2^2 + 
         t1^2 (18 Ss^3 + 22 t1 Ss^2 + 11 t1^2 Ss - t1^3) s2 + 
         Ss t1^3 (2 Ss^2 + 2 t1 Ss - t1^2)) m^6 - 
      Ss (s2 - t1) ((11 t1 - 2 Ss) s2^4 + 
         2 (Ss^2 - 16 t1 Ss - 7 t1^2) s2^3 + 
         6 (4 Ss^2 t1 - t1^3) s2^2 + 
         2 t1^2 (15 Ss^2 + 16 t1 Ss + 5 t1^2) s2 + 
         t1^3 (4 Ss^2 + 2 t1 Ss - t1^2)) m^4 + 
      Ss^2 (s2 - t1)^2 (s2^4 - (Ss + 9 t1) s2^3 + 
         3 (3 Ss - t1) t1 s2^2 + t1^2 (15 Ss + 11 t1) s2 + 
         Ss t1^3) m^2 + 
      Ss^3 (s2 - t1)^3 t1 (s2^2 - 4 t1 s2 + t1^2)) Log[((-m^2 + m2^2 +
         s2 + Sqrt[m^4 - 2 (m2^2 + s2) m^2 + (m2^2 - s2)^2]) (s2 - 
        t1))/(2 s2)] s2^3]
```

The factors in the front of two logarithms are the same, so it can be written in more compact form, i.e. in the form ...Log[.../...]. I tried to implement this by using

```
Collect[F[s2,Ss,t1,m,m2],_Log]
```

or by writing exact function

```
collectLog = {a_*Log[x_] + a_*Log[y_] :> a*Log[x y], 
   b_*Log[x_] - b_*Log[y_] :> b*Log[x/y]};
```

and then

```
F[s2,Ss,t1,m,m2] //. collectLog
```

but these don't work.

How to force Mathematica to collect the logs for the given function?

Comment: Does'nt `Simplify` give you what you want?

Comment: @eldo : evel FullSimplify doesn't... It just collects the multipliers, expressing my function as ...(Log[...] - Log[...]).

Comment: Both `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` seem to work fine for me (giving `bigfactor * (Log[stuff] + Log[morestuff]`). Is it a version thing? I'm on MMA 10.4.

Comment: @aardvark2012 : however, it still doesn't collect the logs to the form Log[a/b]. This is what I want, sorry for unclarity. I updated the question.

Comment: `Simplify[...long expression...] /. -Log[x_] + Log[y_] -> Log[y/x]` works for me

Comment: @yohbs : thank you! Instead of your expression, I used Simplify[...long expression... /. -Log[x_] + Log[y_] -> Log[y/x]], which didn't work.

Comment: @yohbs : but this trick doesn't work, unfortunately, for dynamical expressions. The function I've written appears as the result of an integration, so I write F[...] := Evaluate[Simplify[Integrate[]  /. -Log[x_] + Log[y_] -> Log[y/x]]], and it doesn't work.

Comment: For dynamical expressions, it works with FullSimplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to define a function with required properties which will not have the limiting rules of `Log` on argument values:

```
ln /: ln[x_] + ln[y_] := ln[x y]
ln /: ln[x_] - ln[y_] := ln[x/y]
```

The usage is something like

```
FullSimplify[F[s2,Ss,t1,m,m2]/. Log[$_] -> ln[$]] /. ln[$_] -> Log[$]
```

Comment: Does this in principle require so much time as for the construction 
FullSimplify[] /. -Log[x_] +Log[y_] :> Log[y/x], how do you think?

Comment: @JohnTaylor Idk. Perhaps on a complicated expression one `FullSimplfy` is redundant and dropping it will speed up the evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer in that it doesn't actually solve the problem, but might give you some pointers.

The problem is that `Simplify` doesn't know what you're taking the `Log` of. For example,

```
Simplify[Log[a] - Log[b]]
```

> Log[a] - Log[b]

But

```
Assuming[b > 0, Simplify[Log[a] - Log[b]]]
```

> Log[a/b]

I haven't been able to get the same result with your `F`. Using `Reduce` to find the conditions for which your argument of `Log` is positive, and then building in those conditions with `Assuming` doesn't seem work. Though there might be another way.