# I can't collect the logs in the given expression (continuation)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

This is another question about the [problem of collecting of the logariths](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152801/i-cant-collect-the-logs-in-the-given-expression).

Suppose the function

```
F[s2_, Ss_, t1_, m_, m2_] := 
 Evaluate[-6 ((s2^6 + (Ss - 7 t1) s2^5 + (-4 Ss^2 + 13 t1 Ss + 
            16 t1^2) s2^4 + 
         2 (Ss^3 - 13 t1 Ss^2 - 10 t1^2 Ss - 8 t1^3) s2^3 + 
         t1 (18 Ss^3 + 6 t1 Ss^2 - 4 t1^2 Ss + 7 t1^3) s2^2 + 
         t1^2 (18 Ss^3 + 22 t1 Ss^2 + 11 t1^2 Ss - t1^3) s2 + 
         Ss t1^3 (2 Ss^2 + 2 t1 Ss - t1^2)) m^6 - 
      Ss (s2 - t1) ((11 t1 - 2 Ss) s2^4 + 
         2 (Ss^2 - 16 t1 Ss - 7 t1^2) s2^3 + 
         6 (4 Ss^2 t1 - t1^3) s2^2 + 
         2 t1^2 (15 Ss^2 + 16 t1 Ss + 5 t1^2) s2 + 
         t1^3 (4 Ss^2 + 2 t1 Ss - t1^2)) m^4 + 
      Ss^2 (s2 - t1)^2 (s2^4 - (Ss + 9 t1) s2^3 + 
         3 (3 Ss - t1) t1 s2^2 + t1^2 (15 Ss + 11 t1) s2 + 
         Ss t1^3) m^2 + 
      Ss^3 (s2 - t1)^3 t1 (s2^2 - 4 t1 s2 + t1^2)) Log[((-m^2 + m2^2 +
         s2 - Sqrt[m^4 - 2 (m2^2 + s2) m^2 + (m2^2 - s2)^2]) (s2 - 
        t1))/(2 s2)] s2^3 + 
   6 ((s2^6 + (Ss - 7 t1) s2^5 + (-4 Ss^2 + 13 t1 Ss + 
            16 t1^2) s2^4 + 
         2 (Ss^3 - 13 t1 Ss^2 - 10 t1^2 Ss - 8 t1^3) s2^3 + 
         t1 (18 Ss^3 + 6 t1 Ss^2 - 4 t1^2 Ss + 7 t1^3) s2^2 + 
         t1^2 (18 Ss^3 + 22 t1 Ss^2 + 11 t1^2 Ss - t1^3) s2 + 
         Ss t1^3 (2 Ss^2 + 2 t1 Ss - t1^2)) m^6 - 
      Ss (s2 - t1) ((11 t1 - 2 Ss) s2^4 + 
         2 (Ss^2 - 16 t1 Ss - 7 t1^2) s2^3 + 
         6 (4 Ss^2 t1 - t1^3) s2^2 + 
         2 t1^2 (15 Ss^2 + 16 t1 Ss + 5 t1^2) s2 + 
         t1^3 (4 Ss^2 + 2 t1 Ss - t1^2)) m^4 + 
      Ss^2 (s2 - t1)^2 (s2^4 - (Ss + 9 t1) s2^3 + 
         3 (3 Ss - t1) t1 s2^2 + t1^2 (15 Ss + 11 t1) s2 + 
         Ss t1^3) m^2 + 
      Ss^3 (s2 - t1)^3 t1 (s2^2 - 4 t1 s2 + t1^2)) Log[((-m^2 + m2^2 +
         s2 + Sqrt[m^4 - 2 (m2^2 + s2) m^2 + (m2^2 - s2)^2]) (s2 - 
        t1))/(2 s2)] s2^3]
```

I need to collect the logarithms with the same prefactors to the form Log[.../...]. If I call already **statically** defined function F inside the construction

```
Simplify[F[s2_, Ss_, t1_, m_, m2_]]/. -Log[x_] + Log[y_] -> Log[y/x]
```

the logarithms become to be collected. But if the function F is defined **dynamically** (in my case - because of an integration, see the precise example below), the construction doesn't work. I.e., for

```
F[] := Evaluate[Simplify[Integrate[]]/. -Log[x_] + Log[y_] -> Log[y/x]]
F[]
```

it doesn't work.

Only the construction FullSimplify works, but it requires so many time that I doesn't have the wish to wait. The Simplify construction, on the contrary, works very fast.

So, does anyone know some alternative ways to force Mathematica to collect the logarithms, especially working for dynamically defined functions?

I'm using Mathematica 11.

**Precise example when Simplify doesn't work, but FullSimplify does**

Just to illustrate the problem completely, I add the integral:

```
    f[Ss_,s2_,t1_,t2_,m_,m2_] =1/(32 \[Pi]^3 Ss^3 (s2-t1) (m^2-s2+t1-t2)) (-(((s2^2 t2-s2 t2 (Ss+t1)+Ss t1 (t1-s2)-Ss t1 t2) (s2^2-6 s2 (Ss-t1+t2)+Ss^2+2 Ss (t2-t1)-(t1-t2)^2))/(s2-t1)^2)+(s2-Ss) (s2^2+2 s2 (Ss-2 t1+2 t2)+Ss^2+(t1-t2)^2)-(2 (2 s2-2 Ss+t1-t2) (-2 Ss t1 t2 (s2-t1) (2 s2^2-2 s2 (Ss+t1)-Ss t1)+t2^2 (s2^4-2 s2^3 (Ss+t1)+s2^2 (Ss-t1)^2+4 s2 Ss t1 (Ss+t1)+Ss^2 t1^2)+Ss^2 t1^2 (s2-t1)^2))/(s2-t1)^4-(2 (s2^2 t2-s2 t2 (Ss+t1)+Ss t1 (t1-s2)-Ss t1 t2) (2 Ss t1 t2 (s2-t1) (-4 s2^2+4 s2 (Ss+t1)+Ss t1)+t2^2 (s2^4-2 s2^3 (Ss+t1)+s2^2 (Ss^2-6 Ss t1+t1^2)+8 s2 Ss t1 (Ss+t1)+Ss^2 t1^2)+Ss^2 t1^2 (s2-t1)^2))/(s2-t1)^6)
   F[Ss_,s2_,t1_,m_,m2_]=Assuming[s2> (m+m2)^2 && s2-t1 > 0 && m > 0 && m2 > 0,Simplify[Integrate[f[Ss,s2,t1,t2,m,m2],{t2,t2lower,t2upper}]
    ]]/.-Log[x_]+Log[y_]:> Log[y/x]
```

Here, the code defining the limits of integration is

```
lambda[a_, b_, c_] := a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2*(a*b + a*c + b*c)
t2lower = 
 Simplify[m^2 - 1/(2*s2)*(s2 - t1)*(s2 + m^2 - m2^2) - 
   1/(2*s2)*(s2 - t1)*Sqrt[lambda[s2, m^2, m2^2]]]
t2upper = 
 Simplify[m^2 - 1/(2*s2)*(s2 - t1)*(s2 + m^2 - m2^2) + 
   1/(2*s2)*(s2 - t1)*Sqrt[lambda[s2, m^2, m2^2]]]
```

For this construction, the logs collecting including `Simplify` doesn't work. Changing it to `FullSimplify` works, but it takes a plenty of time. I want to avoid this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Can you please give an example where `FullSimplify` works but `Simplify` does not?  The origin of the expression should not matter, only its content.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : in my specific case it doesn't.

Comment: Two general notes: (1) you can leave out `Evaluate` and define `F` with `Set`, i.e. `F[ . . . ] = def` and (2) you should be using `RuleDelayed` when you have named patterns on the left-hand-side, unless you specifically know otherwise, i.e. `-Log[x_] + Log[y_] :> Log[y/x]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : I've added the precise code to the question, for which Simplify doesn't collect the logarithms (with /. -Log[x_] + Log[y_] :> Log[y/x]), while FullSimplify (with a plenty of time) does.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : I've corrected the example (there weren't definitions for the limits of the integration).

Answer (score 1):

In version 10.1

```
Assuming[s2 > (m + m2)^2 && s2 - t1 > 0 && m > 0 && m2 > 0, 
   Integrate[f[Ss, s2, t1, t2, m, m2], {t2, t2lower, t2upper}]]
```

Yields for me this expression, which I replicate for reference:

```
expr = ConditionalExpression[-((-6 m^4 s2^6 t2lower - 6 m^2 s2^7 t2lower - 
       6 s2^8 t2lower - 6 m^4 s2^5 Ss t2lower - 6 m^2 s2^6 Ss t2lower - 
       6 s2^7 Ss t2lower + 24 m^4 s2^4 Ss^2 t2lower + 12 m^2 s2^5 Ss^2 t2lower + 
       6 s2^6 Ss^2 t2lower - 12 m^4 s2^3 Ss^3 t2lower + 6 s2^5 Ss^3 t2lower + 
       42 m^4 s2^5 t1 t2lower + 48 m^2 s2^6 t1 t2lower + 54 s2^7 t1 t2lower - 
       78 m^4 s2^4 Ss t1 t2lower - 6 m^2 s2^5 Ss t1 t2lower + 
       156 m^4 s2^3 Ss^2 t1 t2lower - 48 m^2 s2^4 Ss^2 t1 t2lower + 
       6 s2^5 Ss^2 t1 t2lower - 108 m^4 s2^2 Ss^3 t1 t2lower + 
       36 m^2 s2^3 Ss^3 t1 t2lower - 30 s2^4 Ss^3 t1 t2lower - 
       96 m^4 s2^4 t1^2 t2lower - 138 m^2 s2^5 t1^2 t2lower - 
       186 s2^6 t1^2 t2lower + 120 m^4 s2^3 Ss t1^2 t2lower + 
       48 m^2 s2^4 Ss t1^2 t2lower + 54 s2^5 Ss t1^2 t2lower - 
       36 m^4 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^2 t2lower - 48 s2^4 Ss^2 t1^2 t2lower - 
       108 m^4 s2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2lower + 36 m^2 s2^2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2lower + 
       24 s2^3 Ss^3 t1^2 t2lower + 96 m^4 s2^3 t1^3 t2lower + 
       192 m^2 s2^4 t1^3 t2lower + 330 s2^5 t1^3 t2lower + 
       24 m^4 s2^2 Ss t1^3 t2lower - 48 m^2 s2^3 Ss t1^3 t2lower - 
       96 s2^4 Ss t1^3 t2lower - 132 m^4 s2 Ss^2 t1^3 t2lower + 
       96 m^2 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^3 t2lower + 48 s2^3 Ss^2 t1^3 t2lower - 
       12 m^4 Ss^3 t1^3 t2lower - 60 m^2 s2 Ss^3 t1^3 t2lower + 
       24 s2^2 Ss^3 t1^3 t2lower - 42 m^4 s2^2 t1^4 t2lower - 
       138 m^2 s2^3 t1^4 t2lower - 330 s2^4 t1^4 t2lower - 
       66 m^4 s2 Ss t1^4 t2lower + 6 m^2 s2^2 Ss t1^4 t2lower + 
       54 s2^3 Ss t1^4 t2lower - 12 m^4 Ss^2 t1^4 t2lower - 
       60 m^2 s2 Ss^2 t1^4 t2lower - 6 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^4 t2lower - 
       12 m^2 Ss^3 t1^4 t2lower - 30 s2 Ss^3 t1^4 t2lower + 6 m^4 s2 t1^5 t2lower + 
       48 m^2 s2^2 t1^5 t2lower + 186 s2^3 t1^5 t2lower + 6 m^4 Ss t1^5 t2lower + 
       6 m^2 s2 Ss t1^5 t2lower - 6 s2 Ss^2 t1^5 t2lower + 6 Ss^3 t1^5 t2lower - 
       6 m^2 s2 t1^6 t2lower - 54 s2^2 t1^6 t2lower - 6 s2 Ss t1^6 t2lower + 
       6 s2 t1^7 t2lower - 3 m^2 s2^6 t2lower^2 - 6 s2^7 t2lower^2 - 
       3 m^2 s2^5 Ss t2lower^2 - 6 s2^6 Ss t2lower^2 + 12 m^2 s2^4 Ss^2 t2lower^2 + 
       18 s2^5 Ss^2 t2lower^2 - 6 m^2 s2^3 Ss^3 t2lower^2 - 6 s2^4 Ss^3 t2lower^2 + 
       21 m^2 s2^5 t1 t2lower^2 + 48 s2^6 t1 t2lower^2 - 
       39 m^2 s2^4 Ss t1 t2lower^2 - 39 s2^5 Ss t1 t2lower^2 + 
       78 m^2 s2^3 Ss^2 t1 t2lower^2 + 42 s2^4 Ss^2 t1 t2lower^2 - 
       54 m^2 s2^2 Ss^3 t1 t2lower^2 - 30 s2^3 Ss^3 t1 t2lower^2 - 
       48 m^2 s2^4 t1^2 t2lower^2 - 138 s2^5 t1^2 t2lower^2 + 
       60 m^2 s2^3 Ss t1^2 t2lower^2 + 123 s2^4 Ss t1^2 t2lower^2 - 
       18 m^2 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^2 t2lower^2 - 96 s2^3 Ss^2 t1^2 t2lower^2 - 
       54 m^2 s2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2lower^2 + 18 s2^2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2lower^2 + 
       48 m^2 s2^3 t1^3 t2lower^2 + 192 s2^4 t1^3 t2lower^2 + 
       12 m^2 s2^2 Ss t1^3 t2lower^2 - 72 s2^3 Ss t1^3 t2lower^2 - 
       66 m^2 s2 Ss^2 t1^3 t2lower^2 - 6 m^2 Ss^3 t1^3 t2lower^2 + 
       18 s2 Ss^3 t1^3 t2lower^2 - 21 m^2 s2^2 t1^4 t2lower^2 - 
       138 s2^3 t1^4 t2lower^2 - 33 m^2 s2 Ss t1^4 t2lower^2 - 
       42 s2^2 Ss t1^4 t2lower^2 - 6 m^2 Ss^2 t1^4 t2lower^2 + 
       30 s2 Ss^2 t1^4 t2lower^2 + 3 m^2 s2 t1^5 t2lower^2 + 
       48 s2^2 t1^5 t2lower^2 + 3 m^2 Ss t1^5 t2lower^2 + 39 s2 Ss t1^5 t2lower^2 + 
       6 Ss^2 t1^5 t2lower^2 - 6 s2 t1^6 t2lower^2 - 3 Ss t1^6 t2lower^2 - 
       2 s2^6 t2lower^3 - 2 s2^5 Ss t2lower^3 + 8 s2^4 Ss^2 t2lower^3 - 
       4 s2^3 Ss^3 t2lower^3 + 14 s2^5 t1 t2lower^3 - 26 s2^4 Ss t1 t2lower^3 + 
       52 s2^3 Ss^2 t1 t2lower^3 - 36 s2^2 Ss^3 t1 t2lower^3 - 
       32 s2^4 t1^2 t2lower^3 + 40 s2^3 Ss t1^2 t2lower^3 - 
       12 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^2 t2lower^3 - 36 s2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2lower^3 + 
       32 s2^3 t1^3 t2lower^3 + 8 s2^2 Ss t1^3 t2lower^3 - 
       44 s2 Ss^2 t1^3 t2lower^3 - 4 Ss^3 t1^3 t2lower^3 - 14 s2^2 t1^4 t2lower^3 - 
       22 s2 Ss t1^4 t2lower^3 - 4 Ss^2 t1^4 t2lower^3 + 2 s2 t1^5 t2lower^3 + 
       2 Ss t1^5 t2lower^3 + 6 m^4 s2^6 t2upper + 6 m^2 s2^7 t2upper + 
       6 s2^8 t2upper + 6 m^4 s2^5 Ss t2upper + 6 m^2 s2^6 Ss t2upper + 
       6 s2^7 Ss t2upper - 24 m^4 s2^4 Ss^2 t2upper - 12 m^2 s2^5 Ss^2 t2upper - 
       6 s2^6 Ss^2 t2upper + 12 m^4 s2^3 Ss^3 t2upper - 6 s2^5 Ss^3 t2upper - 
       42 m^4 s2^5 t1 t2upper - 48 m^2 s2^6 t1 t2upper - 54 s2^7 t1 t2upper + 
       78 m^4 s2^4 Ss t1 t2upper + 6 m^2 s2^5 Ss t1 t2upper - 
       156 m^4 s2^3 Ss^2 t1 t2upper + 48 m^2 s2^4 Ss^2 t1 t2upper - 
       6 s2^5 Ss^2 t1 t2upper + 108 m^4 s2^2 Ss^3 t1 t2upper - 
       36 m^2 s2^3 Ss^3 t1 t2upper + 30 s2^4 Ss^3 t1 t2upper + 
       96 m^4 s2^4 t1^2 t2upper + 138 m^2 s2^5 t1^2 t2upper + 
       186 s2^6 t1^2 t2upper - 120 m^4 s2^3 Ss t1^2 t2upper - 
       48 m^2 s2^4 Ss t1^2 t2upper - 54 s2^5 Ss t1^2 t2upper + 
       36 m^4 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^2 t2upper + 48 s2^4 Ss^2 t1^2 t2upper + 
       108 m^4 s2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2upper - 36 m^2 s2^2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2upper - 
       24 s2^3 Ss^3 t1^2 t2upper - 96 m^4 s2^3 t1^3 t2upper - 
       192 m^2 s2^4 t1^3 t2upper - 330 s2^5 t1^3 t2upper - 
       24 m^4 s2^2 Ss t1^3 t2upper + 48 m^2 s2^3 Ss t1^3 t2upper + 
       96 s2^4 Ss t1^3 t2upper + 132 m^4 s2 Ss^2 t1^3 t2upper - 
       96 m^2 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^3 t2upper - 48 s2^3 Ss^2 t1^3 t2upper + 
       12 m^4 Ss^3 t1^3 t2upper + 60 m^2 s2 Ss^3 t1^3 t2upper - 
       24 s2^2 Ss^3 t1^3 t2upper + 42 m^4 s2^2 t1^4 t2upper + 
       138 m^2 s2^3 t1^4 t2upper + 330 s2^4 t1^4 t2upper + 
       66 m^4 s2 Ss t1^4 t2upper - 6 m^2 s2^2 Ss t1^4 t2upper - 
       54 s2^3 Ss t1^4 t2upper + 12 m^4 Ss^2 t1^4 t2upper + 
       60 m^2 s2 Ss^2 t1^4 t2upper + 6 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^4 t2upper + 
       12 m^2 Ss^3 t1^4 t2upper + 30 s2 Ss^3 t1^4 t2upper - 6 m^4 s2 t1^5 t2upper - 
       48 m^2 s2^2 t1^5 t2upper - 186 s2^3 t1^5 t2upper - 6 m^4 Ss t1^5 t2upper - 
       6 m^2 s2 Ss t1^5 t2upper + 6 s2 Ss^2 t1^5 t2upper - 6 Ss^3 t1^5 t2upper + 
       6 m^2 s2 t1^6 t2upper + 54 s2^2 t1^6 t2upper + 6 s2 Ss t1^6 t2upper - 
       6 s2 t1^7 t2upper + 3 m^2 s2^6 t2upper^2 + 6 s2^7 t2upper^2 + 
       3 m^2 s2^5 Ss t2upper^2 + 6 s2^6 Ss t2upper^2 - 12 m^2 s2^4 Ss^2 t2upper^2 - 
       18 s2^5 Ss^2 t2upper^2 + 6 m^2 s2^3 Ss^3 t2upper^2 + 6 s2^4 Ss^3 t2upper^2 - 
       21 m^2 s2^5 t1 t2upper^2 - 48 s2^6 t1 t2upper^2 + 
       39 m^2 s2^4 Ss t1 t2upper^2 + 39 s2^5 Ss t1 t2upper^2 - 
       78 m^2 s2^3 Ss^2 t1 t2upper^2 - 42 s2^4 Ss^2 t1 t2upper^2 + 
       54 m^2 s2^2 Ss^3 t1 t2upper^2 + 30 s2^3 Ss^3 t1 t2upper^2 + 
       48 m^2 s2^4 t1^2 t2upper^2 + 138 s2^5 t1^2 t2upper^2 - 
       60 m^2 s2^3 Ss t1^2 t2upper^2 - 123 s2^4 Ss t1^2 t2upper^2 + 
       18 m^2 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^2 t2upper^2 + 96 s2^3 Ss^2 t1^2 t2upper^2 + 
       54 m^2 s2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2upper^2 - 18 s2^2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2upper^2 - 
       48 m^2 s2^3 t1^3 t2upper^2 - 192 s2^4 t1^3 t2upper^2 - 
       12 m^2 s2^2 Ss t1^3 t2upper^2 + 72 s2^3 Ss t1^3 t2upper^2 + 
       66 m^2 s2 Ss^2 t1^3 t2upper^2 + 6 m^2 Ss^3 t1^3 t2upper^2 - 
       18 s2 Ss^3 t1^3 t2upper^2 + 21 m^2 s2^2 t1^4 t2upper^2 + 
       138 s2^3 t1^4 t2upper^2 + 33 m^2 s2 Ss t1^4 t2upper^2 + 
       42 s2^2 Ss t1^4 t2upper^2 + 6 m^2 Ss^2 t1^4 t2upper^2 - 
       30 s2 Ss^2 t1^4 t2upper^2 - 3 m^2 s2 t1^5 t2upper^2 - 
       48 s2^2 t1^5 t2upper^2 - 3 m^2 Ss t1^5 t2upper^2 - 39 s2 Ss t1^5 t2upper^2 - 
       6 Ss^2 t1^5 t2upper^2 + 6 s2 t1^6 t2upper^2 + 3 Ss t1^6 t2upper^2 + 
       2 s2^6 t2upper^3 + 2 s2^5 Ss t2upper^3 - 8 s2^4 Ss^2 t2upper^3 + 
       4 s2^3 Ss^3 t2upper^3 - 14 s2^5 t1 t2upper^3 + 26 s2^4 Ss t1 t2upper^3 - 
       52 s2^3 Ss^2 t1 t2upper^3 + 36 s2^2 Ss^3 t1 t2upper^3 + 
       32 s2^4 t1^2 t2upper^3 - 40 s2^3 Ss t1^2 t2upper^3 + 
       12 s2^2 Ss^2 t1^2 t2upper^3 + 36 s2 Ss^3 t1^2 t2upper^3 - 
       32 s2^3 t1^3 t2upper^3 - 8 s2^2 Ss t1^3 t2upper^3 + 
       44 s2 Ss^2 t1^3 t2upper^3 + 4 Ss^3 t1^3 t2upper^3 + 14 s2^2 t1^4 t2upper^3 + 
       22 s2 Ss t1^4 t2upper^3 + 4 Ss^2 t1^4 t2upper^3 - 2 s2 t1^5 t2upper^3 - 
       2 Ss t1^5 t2upper^3 - 
       6 (Ss^3 (s2 - t1)^3 t1 (s2^2 - 4 s2 t1 + t1^2) + 
          m^2 Ss^2 (s2 - t1)^2 (s2^4 + 3 s2^2 (3 Ss - t1) t1 + Ss t1^3 - 
             s2^3 (Ss + 9 t1) + s2 t1^2 (15 Ss + 11 t1)) - 
          m^4 Ss (s2 - t1) (s2^4 (-2 Ss + 11 t1) + 
             2 s2^3 (Ss^2 - 16 Ss t1 - 7 t1^2) + t1^3 (4 Ss^2 + 2 Ss t1 - t1^2) + 
             2 s2 t1^2 (15 Ss^2 + 16 Ss t1 + 5 t1^2) + 6 s2^2 (4 Ss^2 t1 - t1^3)) + 
          m^6 (s2^6 + s2^5 (Ss - 7 t1) + Ss t1^3 (2 Ss^2 + 2 Ss t1 - t1^2) + 
             s2^4 (-4 Ss^2 + 13 Ss t1 + 16 t1^2) + 
             2 s2^3 (Ss^3 - 13 Ss^2 t1 - 10 Ss t1^2 - 8 t1^3) + 
             s2 t1^2 (18 Ss^3 + 22 Ss^2 t1 + 11 Ss t1^2 - t1^3) + 
             s2^2 t1 (18 Ss^3 + 6 Ss^2 t1 - 4 Ss t1^2 + 7 t1^3))) Log[-m^2 + s2 - 
          t1 + t2lower] + 
       6 (Ss^3 (s2 - t1)^3 t1 (s2^2 - 4 s2 t1 + t1^2) + 
          m^2 Ss^2 (s2 - t1)^2 (s2^4 + 3 s2^2 (3 Ss - t1) t1 + Ss t1^3 - 
             s2^3 (Ss + 9 t1) + s2 t1^2 (15 Ss + 11 t1)) - 
          m^4 Ss (s2 - t1) (s2^4 (-2 Ss + 11 t1) + 
             2 s2^3 (Ss^2 - 16 Ss t1 - 7 t1^2) + t1^3 (4 Ss^2 + 2 Ss t1 - t1^2) + 
             2 s2 t1^2 (15 Ss^2 + 16 Ss t1 + 5 t1^2) + 6 s2^2 (4 Ss^2 t1 - t1^3)) + 
          m^6 (s2^6 + s2^5 (Ss - 7 t1) + Ss t1^3 (2 Ss^2 + 2 Ss t1 - t1^2) + 
             s2^4 (-4 Ss^2 + 13 Ss t1 + 16 t1^2) + 
             2 s2^3 (Ss^3 - 13 Ss^2 t1 - 10 Ss t1^2 - 8 t1^3) + 
             s2 t1^2 (18 Ss^3 + 22 Ss^2 t1 + 11 Ss t1^2 - t1^3) + 
             s2^2 t1 (18 Ss^3 + 6 Ss^2 t1 - 4 Ss t1^2 + 7 t1^3))) Log[-m^2 + s2 - 
          t1 + t2upper])/(192 \[Pi]^3 Ss^3 (s2 - t1)^7)), (Re[(
       m^2 - s2 + t1 - t2lower)/(
       t2lower - t2upper)] < -1 && (Re[(-m^2 + s2 - t1 + t2lower)/(
         t2lower - t2upper)] == 0 || 
       Re[(-m^2 + s2 - t1 + t2lower)/(t2lower - t2upper)] >= 1)) || (
    m^2 - s2 + t1 - t2lower)/(t2lower - t2upper) \[NotElement] 
    Reals || (Re[(m^2 - s2 + t1 - t2lower)/(t2lower - t2upper)] >= 0 && 
     Re[(-m^2 + s2 - t1 + t2lower)/(t2lower - t2upper)] < 0)]
```

I think this might do what you want.  There are only two Log expressions and they are contiguous.

```
Position[expr[[1]], _Log]
```

> ```
> {{5, 265, 3}, {5, 266, 3}}
> ```

If we extract them, simplify, and replace them in the original:

```
old = expr[[1, 5, 265 ;; 266]];
new = Simplify[old] /. -Log[x_] + Log[y_] :> Log[y/x];

expr /. old -> new
```

In which appears `Log[(-m^2 + s2 - t1 + t2upper)/(-m^2 + s2 - t1 + t2lower)]`

You might be able to use `Collect[expr[[1]], _Log]` first if the expression is not of this form.  Or all this might be a terrible idea, as I think I'm falling asleep.  Good luck. :^)