# How to force Mathematica to display output (after integration) with logs in the form of Log[a/b]?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, syntax

Suppose the function

```
f[Ss_,s2_,m_,m2_] = (12 s2 (2 s2^3-6 s2^2 Ss+3 s2 Ss^2+Ss^3) log((m2^2 s2)/(s2-m^2)^2)-12 log(s2/Ss) (s2 (2 s2^3-6 s2^2 Ss+3 s2 Ss^2-Ss^3)-3 s2 Ss^3 log((m2^2 s2)/(s2-m^2)^2))+s2 (46 s2^3-117 s2^2 Ss+72 s2 Ss^2-Ss^3))/(1152 \[Pi]^3 s2 Ss^3)
```

Is there any way to force the integral

```
Integrate[f[Ss,s2,m,m2], {s2, (m+m2)^2, Ss}, Assumptions -> Ss > (m+m2)^2 && m > m2 && m2 > 0]
```

which includes logarithms, to be displayed in the appropriate form with Log[a/b]?

The "nake" output contains pieces like

```
178 Ss^3 m^2 + 288 Ss^3 log^2(m + m2) m^2 + 
 72 Ss^3 log^2(m2 (2 m + m2)) m^2 - 72 Ss^3 log^2(1 - m^2/Ss) m^2 - 
 72 Ss^3 log^2(Ss) m^2 + 96 Ss^3 log(m + m2) m^2 + 
 144 Ss^3 log(2 m + m2) m^2 - 
 288 Ss^3 log(m + m2) log(2 m + m2) m^2 - 
 144 Ss^3 log(m2 (2 m + m2)) m^2 + 144 Ss^3 log(1 - m^2/Ss) m^2 + 
 24 Ss^3 log(m2^2/(m^2 - Ss)^2) m^2 + 48 Ss^3 log(Ss) m^2 - 
 144 Ss^3 log(m + m2) log(Ss) m^2 - 
 144 Ss^3 log(1 - m^2/Ss) log(Ss) m^2 - 
 72 Ss^3 log(m2^2/(m^2 - Ss)^2) log(Ss) m^2 + 
 144 Ss^3 PolyLog[2,-(m^2/(m2^2 + 2 m m2))] m^2 - 
 144 Ss^3 PolyLog[2,m^2/(m^2 - Ss)] m^2
```

and I even can't guess its compact form. **(Added)** By the compact form I mean precise constructions of the form `Log[Ss/(Ss-m^2)], Log[m2^2/Ss]^2` and similar to these.

`FullSimplify[]/. -Log[x_] + Log[y_] :> Log[y/x]` doesn't work.

Input:

```
ln /: ln[x_] + ln[y_] := ln[x y]
ln /: ln[x_] - ln[y_] := ln[x/y]
f[Ss_, s2_, m_, m2_] = \!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(1152\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(3\)]\ s2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ss\), \(3\)]\)] \((12\ s2\ \((2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(s2\), \(3\)] - 6\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(s2\), \(2\)]\ Ss + 3\ s2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ss\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ss\), \(3\)])\)\ Log[
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m2\), \(2\)]\ s2\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((s2 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)])\), \(2\)]]] - 
      12\ Log[s2/Ss] \((\((s2 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)])\)\ \((2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(s2\), \(3\)] - 6\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(s2\), \(2\)]\ Ss + 3\ s2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ss\), \(2\)] - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ss\), \(3\)])\) - 3\ s2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ss\), \(3\)]\ Log[
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m2\), \(2\)]\ s2\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((s2 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)])\), \(2\)]]])\) + \((s2 - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)])\)\ \((46\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(s2\), \(3\)] - 117\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(s2\), \(2\)]\ Ss + 72\ s2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ss\), \(2\)] - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ss\), \(3\)])\))\)\)
G[Ss_, m_, m2_] = 
 Integrate[f[Ss, s2, m, m2], {s2, (m + m2)^2, Ss}, 
  Assumptions -> Ss > (m + m2)^2 && m > m2 && m2 > 0]
FullSimplify[G[Ss, m, m2] /. Log[$_] -> ln[$]] /. ln[$_] -> Log[$]
```

Comment: log is not the same as Log. log( ) is not the same as Log[ ].

Comment: @bills: the same problem with Log remains, I've already tried to replace.

Comment: @JohnTaylor the answer I gave on this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152801/i-cant-collect-the-logs-in-the-given-expression (edited) works.

Comment: @Andrew : this sounds fine, and I'll try it now.

Comment: `res=Integrate[..];`
`FullSimplify[res /. Log[$_] -> ln[$]] /. ln[$_] -> Log[$]`
works for me.

Comment: @Andrew : Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me... That's strange. Maybe the only reason is that the function f (which is needed to be integrated) from my question also is evaluated dynamically... I'm going to define it statically, from the output, and check whether this will help or not.

Comment: @Andrew : Maybe I do something wrong, but even for statically defined f, the simplification doesn't work.  Could you please tell me whether my input (see the modified question) coincides with your?

Comment: @JohnTaylor I run the input, in one place there appeared a logarithm of a fraction.

Comment: @Andrew : sorry, does the output still contain things like Log[m+m2]?

Comment: @JohnTaylor Yes, lots of logarithmic terms.

Comment: @Andrew : unfortunately, this is not I want... I just want to collect the terms in combinations like Log[(Ss-m^2)/m2^2]...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the answer is following.

First, instead of definite integration, let's perform indefinite integration. The reason is that the logs are collected in original function $f$, so the same thing is expected for its integral. After that, using Andrew's answer, one just takes the difference of the integral evaluated at boundary points. The total code is

```
ln /: ln[x_] + ln[y_] := ln[x y]
ln /: ln[x_] - ln[y_] := ln[x/y]
f[Ss,s2,...] = ...
G1[Ss, s2] = Integrate[f[...], s2]
G = FullSimplify[(G[Ss, Ss,...] - G[Ss, (m+m2)^2])/. Log[$_] -> ln[$]] /. ln[$_] -> Log[$]
```

The answer is almost perfect...